# Discussions around senility in politicians

Tags: discussion, answers, declined-flags

Is there any stance on talk around politicians being senile and stating that it is okay for one to be senile but not okay for their opponent to be senile? I am asking this as I see an answer stating that and going on to say that for one it will have no impact but for the other it would be a major impact.

I raised a flag on this issue and it was declined stating we should not raise flags based on the answer being right or wrong. However I feel that we should not be condoning the idea that it is okay for one politician but not for another.

https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/84044/20715

Answer (score 6):

I don't think users are allowed to say that a presidential candidate is senile without very convincing evidence. I've deleted two answers on that question for making such allegations. I left the following comment in those cases:

> I'm going to delete this per the [harmful political content policy of our code of conduct](https://politics.stackexchange.com/conduct/political-speech). You make serious allegations which you have not backed up by evidence. Further, we do not allow discriminatory content towards someone's disability (in this case [Biden's stutter](https://www.uclahealth.org/news/joe-bidens-history-of-stuttering-sheds-light-on-the-condition)).

As for the answer you're referring to in your meta question here, I don't think the answer makes such allegations. That answer makes the argument that you don't need a competent person in charge if you want something to be run poorly. It may not be a good answer, but I don't think it should be removed for code of conduct related reasons.